Irregular Safety Properties
A regular safety property is a safety property whose bad prefixes form a regular language, https://moves.rwth-aachen.de/wp-content/uploads/WS1920/MC/mc2019_handout_lec4.pdf. My questions is, are there any interesting or easy examples of safety properties that are not regular and a proof to show as such.

Can you define what is a regular safety property, and bad prefixes inside the question's body?
